# Facebook Test Users: Liking Pages

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-test-users

I am making an app that requires users to have liked Facebook pages before using the app. I know the Test Users documentation says Tests Users cannot like Facebook Pages, I found that if a Test User creates its own Facebook Page it can like it. However, I can't find a way to access these likes, something I need to know how to do when testing my app. Anyone know how?

Comment: you do know that like gates are not allowed anymore, right?

Comment: Yes, right there in the documentation: "Test users cannot become a fan of a public Facebook Page" https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users#managetool But I can't think of a good reason why this is not enabled for test users. Have you found any answer to this?